# Color the edges of K6 by three colors so that there is no monochromatic cycle.

Tags: graph-theory

Is it possible to color the edges of K6 by three colors so that there is no monochromatic cycle? I tried many times but always end up getting monochromatic cycle.

Answer (score 2):

If one colour is used on at least $6$ edges there will be a cycle of that colour since there are only $6$ vertices. Hence each colour must be used $5$ times.

Here is a symmetric solution:

```
Colour 1: 01 15 52 24 43
Colour 2: 23 31 14 40 05
Colour 3: 45 53 30 02 21
```